# First background image is pushing second one

Tags: css

When i increase the verical position of first background image it disturbs the second image(one with name body png) here is live view http://jsfiddle.net/NsFUr/

```
body{
background-image: url(http://www.muslimdistrict.com/themes/muslimDistricts/images/member_login1.png), url(http://www.muslimdistrict.com/themes/muslimDistricts/images/body_bg.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat,repeat-x;
background-position: -50px 28px;
}
```

i want to make second image stay on its location.Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what it's actually meant to look like? It isn't clear from your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you need to separate the [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) for each image separately by using a `,`

```
background-position: -50px 28px, 0 0;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NsFUr/1/)

Where, the first 2, which are `-50px` and `28px` are the `X` and `Y` for the first `background` whereas `0 0` are `X` and `Y` for your second `background`

Comment: thanks very much i dont have words to thank you. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a different position setting for the other image.

```
   body{
    background-image: url(http://www.muslimdistrict.com/themes/muslimDistricts/images/member_login1.png), url(http://www.muslimdistrict.com/themes/muslimDistricts/images/body_bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat,repeat-x;
    background-position: -50px 28px, position position;
    }
```

[**JSFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wHMwp/)